# Display data with jquery ajax without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I found an ajax form script to display data without reloading the page. Everything is okay but I want to display variable values in a table when the form is submitted. Here is the link that I found [Jquery ajax tutorial](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/) and below is my code. Please help me.

index.php

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <form action="" id="demoForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Demo form</legend>
      <span style="font-size: 0.9em;">This ajax submit demo form.</span>
      <p>
        <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" style="float: right; clear: both; margin-right: 3px;" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div id="message" style="display: none;"> </div>
  <div id="waiting" style="display: none;"> Please wait<br />
    <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" title="Loader" alt="Loader" /> 
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxSubmit.js"></script>
```

ajaxSubmit.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {

        $('#waiting').show(500);
        //$('#demoForm').hide(0);
        $('#message').hide(0);

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'post.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                email : $('#email').val()
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#waiting').hide(500);
                $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                    .text(data.msg).show(500);
                if (data.error === true)
                    $('#demoForm').show(500);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#waiting').hide(500);
                $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                $('#demoForm').show(500);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

post.php

```
<?php
sleep(3);

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';
}
else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $_POST['email'] . '.';
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? There is no `table` currently in your code.

Comment: i want to show $return['msg'] data in table when form is submit

Comment: Have you tried printing `data` inside success handler?

Comment: @Manan I just ran your code on my machine and it worked as expected. I entered a string and it displayed it at the bottom of the `div` without any page refresh.

Comment: yes and i got the values in post.php file. now i want to echo result value in div or in table. don't know how to do that :(

Comment: instead of .text() you could use the .html() function to write html to the inside of your #message div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
success : function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#waiting').hide(500);
    $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
        .text(data[0].msg).show(500);
    if (data[0].error === true)
        $('#demoForm').show(500);
},
```